# Função alert em Jquery

Tags: jquery

Bom dia!

Alguém sabe me dizer uma forma de encontrar erros de sintaxe com facilidade no Jquery?

Tenho um código simples de "alert" que funciona de um jeito, mas não de outro...

Assim funciona, porém bugado:

```
<script>
$(window).click(function(){
    $('.card.Billet')
    alert("teste");
});
</script>
```

Porém o alert fica super bugado e tudo o que carrega ou clica aparece o alerta.

Na segunda opção, tentando compreender como funciona a estrutura do codigo, fiz assim, porém não funcionou:

```
<script>
$('.card.Billet').click(function(){ 
    alert("teste");
});
</script>
```

Html:

```
<label class="card Billet"><input type="radio" value="Billet" class="rdoCreditCards" name="CreditCardProvider" id="CreditCardProvider" displayname="Boleto"><span><small>Boleto</small></span></label>
```

Comment: Gabriel, para darmos uma resposta adequada teríamos que ver o **HTML** como está, mas, só pelo js o primeiro código tudo que clica dispara o alert, pq você vinculou o evento **clique** no elemento `window` ou seja clicar em qualquer lugar da janela vai disparar o alert. Já no segundo código não funciona pq talvez não esteja declarada as classes **card** e **Billet** no Html.

Comment: Adicionei o HTML na pergunta bro, na verdade se trata de um elemento só, porém como no css eu faço xyz.xyz.xyz eu fiz assim, sem o espaço, e sim com o (.)

Comment: Tira o ponto que funciona:
de: `.card.Billet`
para: `.card`

Answer (score -1):

```html
Primeiro de um espaço entre as suas classes css

$('.card .Billet')

depois adicione
e.preventDefault();

vai ficar assim:

$('.card .Billet').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("teste");
});
```

Comment: @Daniel Pyres não funcionou bro, mas a sintaxe então está correta?

Comment: Esta certo sim.
muda o seu html 
<label class="card Billet"><input id="teste" type="radio" value="Billet" class="rdoCreditCards" name="CreditCardProvider" id="CreditCardProvider" displayname="Boleto"><span><small>Boleto</small></span></label>
para
<label class="card Billet"><input type="radio" value="Billet" class="rdoCreditCards" name="CreditCardProvider" id="CreditCardProvider" displayname="Boleto"><span><small>Boleto</small></span></label>

Comment: e muda 
$('.card .Billet').click(function(){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("teste");
});

$('#teste').click(function(){
    alert("teste");
});

se o alert funcionar, o problema é na sua chamada css ou js

Comment: caso continue com duvida, visite o site: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Comment: só mais uma coisa, notei que vc colocou o seu input, dentro do label. Normalmente isso não influencia o js em nada, mas da uma olhada nisso ai. nao sei se isso esta dentro de uma tag <form>, se estiver pode dar erro sim.